# Swing MVC - Data in Model

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, jtextfield

I'm starting to learn how implement MVC pattern in swing. I have a confusion when in comes to the data in model.

In the application that I'm doing, I have several JTextFields. The data set in the fields come from JTable. I have a `ListSelectionListener` in my controller added to that jtable (in the view) so that when selection has changed, the data from the selected row will be reflected to the respective textfields

```
    public void transferTableDataToFields(){
        if(tblProduct.getSelectedRows().length != 0){
            int selRow = tblProduct.getSelectedRow();
            txtID.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(selRow, 0).toString());
            txtName.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(selRow, 1).toString());
            txtDescIn.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(selRow, 2).toString());
            txtSupplier.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(selRow, 4).toString());
            txtPrice.setText(tblProduct.getValueAt(selRow, 5).toString());
        }
    }
```

My question is, am I doing it the right way? Should I define fields in the model that corresponds to the textfields in my view, then change my code to controller setting the model's fields to values from view's jtable then let the model fire a property change notification to its listener, then let the listener call the update method in the view based on the property change event?

My problem with this approach is that, the view should have a method that will return the row selected from the jtable which I find a bit ugly.

**EDIT**

@trashgod this is what I'm saying.

Inside my TableModel implementation, is it better to populate the data here?

```
public MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
   List<Row> data;
   Row header;

   public MyTableModel(){
      initializeData();
   }   

   public void initializeData{
      //query database here then put it in the list
   }
   //other methods to implement e.g. getvalueAt(int x, inty){data.get(x).get(y);}
}
```

Is it better if I make it like this? because currently I stored and populate the data of my table in my main model (also containing fields with corresponding textfields in the `SelectedRow` view) then I pass the data in my `JTable`'s model.

Comment: I think that XxxTableModel could be model for ....

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the current selection is a property of the view, an instance of `JTable`, *not* the model, an implementation of `TableModel`.

If you choose to supersede [editing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in the `JTable` itself, a `ListSelectionListener` is the correct way to update your (anonymous) dependent view, e.g. `SelectedRow`.  Your controller should have little to do except add `SelectedRow` as a listener to your `JTable`. As `SelectedRow` contains (presumably) editable fields, you are responsible for several things:

- Propagate any changes back to the original table's `TableModel`, typically via `setValueAt()`.
- Convert between view and model coordinates, mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).
- Preclude (or synchronize via the `ListSelectionListener`) editing in the source `JTable`.

Addendum: *Inside my* `TableModel` *implementation, is it better to populate the data here?*

The answer depends on the application. Your `TableModel` implementation should expose a public API that provides as much (or as little) as required to support the application's requirements for concurrency and latency. For reference, [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) is a general purpose example, although you'll want to use something more recent than `Vector` internally.

Comment: I appreciate that u took time to answer my question but I'm not sure I understood u well. So ok, first, ur saying that the selected index in my jtable should be a property of my view. What do you mean by `ListSelectionListener` is the correct way to update my (anon) dependet view e.g. `SelectedRow`?

Comment: To clarify: You have two views sharing data from the same model. One view is a `JTable` having a current selection; the other is an unnamed view having several `JTextField` instances. I refer to that unnamed view using the identifier `SelectedRow`. `SelectedRow` listens to `JTable` for its current selection using a `ListSelectionListener`. If you're still having trouble, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that uses the identifiers you prefer.

Comment: I get it now and that is exactly what I'm going through. 1 model with 2 view. Wait, in your first paragraph are u also saying that my view should also provide a getter for the instance of my JTable?

Comment: `SelectedRow` will need a reference to its parent `JTable` so that it may access the `TableModel` and convert between view and model coordinates.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I have another question. Is it good if I just put the data that Im going to show in my `JTable` inside my implementation of `TableModel`? In that way I'm going to have 2 view and 2 model.

Comment: Yes, the data goes in the [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). No, one [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) should be sufficient.